# IE: indexOf results in "object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, indexof

I have the following if statement:

```
if (buyArray.indexOf(dealWith,0) != -1){
```

Which is breaking in ie (ie 8 on XP) with "object doesn't support this property or method".

Anyone have a work around for this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

yeah, IE<9 doesn't support `indexOf`. You can implement a shim like the one showed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Or if you already using jQuery you can use [inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/). Also [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf) has an implementation for it.

Comment: jQuery.inArray is my saviour. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: +1 for the right answer, plus providing work-arounds. The lesson here is to know that old IE versions have a lot of missing functionality, and to be prepared to work around them.

Answer (score 20):

Simply changed to the use jQuery.inArray. Thanks to ZER0 for the heads up

```
if ($.inArray(dealWith, buyArray) != -1) {
```

Comment: You should add the jQuery tag to your question IMO.

Comment: So he gave you the answer then you decided to post it and accept your own as the answer?

Comment: @Blackunknown He pointed me to where I could find the solution and I answered with the actual solution which he helped me to find. So if you are going to be pedantic about it, the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: TBF, you should have given the answer to ZER0

Comment: To fold to popular opinion. I have updated the accepted answer to @ZER0